# With mean(), inf is displayed in the table for no apparent reason

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I would like to take the average of the value from 5 data sets (lan/log/Value). All of the data sets show 64801 rows and have the same lan and log data!

```
def Timeseries(dfn):
    df = dfn
    df_00_10=df.loc[df['filename'].isin(['1964_12_O18grid.csv','1965_12_O18grid.csv','1967_12_O18grid.csv','1968_12_O18grid.csv','1969_12_O18grid.csv'])]
    dfalT=df_00_10.groupby(['Latitude', 'Longitude'], as_index=False)['Value'].mean().reset_index()
    return dfalT
```

However, the table I am calculating only has 64748 rows and shows this in the last row:

```
       index  Latitude  Longitude     Value
0          0     -89.9     -180.0 -7.652547
1          1     -89.9     -179.0 -7.648228
2          2     -89.9     -178.0 -7.644059
3          3     -89.9     -177.0 -7.639989
4          4     -89.9     -176.0 -7.636191
...      ...       ...        ...       ...
64743  64743      89.1      176.0 -7.923986
64744  64744      89.1      177.0 -7.914472
64745  64745      89.1      178.0 -7.905442
64746  64746      89.1      179.0 -7.896940
64747  64747       inf        inf -8.326585
```

However I can´t finde a 0 Value which could be the reason for this!

How can I get around this?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any `inf` as values for `Latitude` and `Longitude`?

Comment: Yes I checked it several times

Comment: There are less rows in `dfalT` than in `df_00_10` because you have grouped the data.  This suggests that there are `64801 - 64748` occurrences where there is data with the same latitude and longitude.  To see if there are any values that fall under the category `inf`, see if the length of the result DataFrame is greater than `0`: `len(df[df["Latitude"] == np.inf])`.  If this is greater than zero, then you can use this: `df_00_10.replace(np.inf, np.nan)`.